# Is it possible to set EventBridge ScheduleExpression value from SSM in Serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I want to schedule one lambda via AWS EventBridge. The issue is I want to read the number value used in `ScheduledExpression` from SSM variable **GCHeartbeatInterval**

Code I used is below

```
heartbeat-check:
      handler: groupconsultation/heartbeatcheck.handler
      description: ${self:custom.gitVersion}
      timeout: 15
      memorySize: 1536
      package:
        include:
          - groupconsultation/heartbeatcheck.js
          - shared/*
          - newrelic-lambda-wrapper.js
      events:
        - eventBridge:
           enabled: true
           schedule: rate(2 minutes)
resources:
 Resources:
    GCHeartbeatInterval:
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
      Properties:
        Name: /${file(vars.js):values.environmentName}/lambda/HeartbeatInterval
        Type: String
        Value: 1  
        Description: value in minute. need to convert it to seconds/milliseconds
```

Is this possible to achieve in serverless.yml ?

Reason for reading it from SSM is, it's a heartbeat service and the same value will be used by FE to send a heartbeat in set interval. BE lambda needs to be triggerred after 2x heartbeat interval

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's not possible. Only solution to it was to pass the variable as a command line argument. something like below.

```
custom:
  mySchedule: ${opt:mySchedule, 1}  # Allow overrides from CLI

...
schedule: ${self:custom.mySchedule}
...

resources:
  Resources:
    GCHeartbeatInterval:
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
      Properties:
        Name: /${file(vars.js):values.environmentName}/lambda/HeartbeatInterval
        Type: String
        Value: ${self:custom.mySchedule}
```

With the other approach, if we  make it work we still have to redeploy the application as we do need to redeploy in this case also.